# PHPStorm однострочный /** @vardoc */ вместо многострочного

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

Коллеги, как настроить PHPStorm, чтобы он вставлял однострочный `/** @vardoc */` комментарий?

Версия PhpStorm 2017.2.4
Build #PS-172.4155.41, built on September 15, 2017
Windows 10 10.0

Собственно причина вопроса. Когда я хочу задокументировать переменную или свойство класса, как гласят все доки, набираю `/**` и нажимаю `Enter`. PHPStorm если распознает тип переменной/свойства, но создает многострочный @vardoc

```
/**
 * @var null|integer
 */
public $msId = null;
```

А мне хочется, чтобы этот vardoc был однострочным. Вот так:

```
/** @var null|array */
public $msId = null;
```

Вот как его заставить делать однострочные @vardoc's ??? 
Может это более старые версии делали такие комментарии, а новая версия не поддерживает?
В настройках не нашел ничего на эту тему
[image: PHPStorm settings]

Comment: Нажать не энтер а пробел?

Comment: Дружище, спасибо) Напиши ответ